# How to initialize and use UI elements

Tags: android, kotlin

I am currently working on my first Android app using Kotlin. In my activity are a lot of UI elements which I use to show dynamic information (see example below). For performance reasons I learned:

> "Define a variable in the class and initialize it in the onCreate()
> method."

This is kind of messy and my question is: are there other techniques to fulfill the same task but have a cleaner code? The variables are used in other methods later.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var text_1: TextView
    private lateinit var text_2: TextView
    private lateinit var text_3: TextView
    private lateinit var text_4: TextView
    [...]

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        text_1 = findViewById(R.id.text1)
        text_2 = findViewById(R.id.text2)
        text_3 = findViewById(R.id.text3)
        text_4 = findViewById(R.id.text4)
        [...]
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Comment: Check the ViewBinding: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [ViewBinding official docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#setup):

> View binding is a feature that allows you to more easily write code that interacts with views

First, enable ViewBinding in your module:

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}
```

Then, if you're calling views from activity, you should:

```
private lateinit var binding: ResultProfileBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)
}
```

and then you use binding instance to call the views:

```
binding.name.text = viewModel.name
binding.button.setOnClickListener { viewModel.userClicked() }
```

If you are calling views from a fragment, you should do it like following to avoid leaks:

```
private var _binding: ResultProfileBinding? = null
// This property is only valid between onCreateView and
// onDestroyView.
private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    _binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    val view = binding.root
    return view
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks for the answer. Maybe you can add, that "ResultProfileBinding" is derived from the activity name. I did not realize that until I read the official documentation you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you just need to use the id directly without binding. The class will import this:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.<your_layout_xml>.*
```

In this case it will `import: kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        text_1.text = "Text1"
        text_2.text = "Text2"
        [...]
}
```

Comment: This is comfortable and works perfect. But then I read a little bit about it and saw a comment, that it is not recommended anymore: https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/882241

Comment: I'm not sure why they not recommend it. But it may cause confuse since you can accident cause crash if use with this way:

``vpMain.run { setOnClickListener {  tvTitle.text = "" } }``.

tvTitle will find in vpMain, not in the MainActivity => NPE appear
I still using it like other still using findViewById and because i like short code